# node.js child_process.spawn - process runs but events don't fire

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble trapping events for a child process in node.js. The process runs correctly, and exits when it's done, so all's fine there. Stdout also pipes correctly, so I can see the output fine. Unfortunately none of my event handlers ever fire, which makes it difficult for me to run my callback when the process is done. My code is below:

```
var child = child_process.spawn('node',
    ['processor', reportId.toString()],
    { cwd:cwd, stdio:'pipe', env:env });

child.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received data...');
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});
child.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('Received message...');
    console.log(message);
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('Child process closed');
});
child.on('disconnect', function(code) {
    console.log('Child process disconnected');
    callback();
});
child.on('exit', function(code) {
    console.log('Child exited with code ' + code);
    callback();
});
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr, { end:true });
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, { end:true });
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but none of the documentation seems to offer a clue as to what the problem might be. Any ideas?

I'm running node 0.10.8 on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spawn doesn't have the same ipc channel built in that [fork](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) does so the **message** event won't fire unless you enable it:

```
var child = child_process.spawn('node', ['processor', reportId.toString()],{
    cwd:cwd, 
    env:env,
    stdio:['ipc'] //enable ipc channel
});
```

The **data** event should be on the stdout of child instead of the child itself:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received data...');
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns that it's also helpful to verify one's assumption that the child process is in fact exiting! In my case, something was preventing it from closing, which meant naturally none of the expected events were firing.

Comment: fork may be a better fit in your situation since you need communication between parent and child processes. Here's a module I wrote that simplified it: https://npmjs.org/package/farmhand